# Multinomial logistic regression - variable data available only in one of the categories

Tags: regression, logistic, classification

I have a data set of accidents with dependent variable of 3 levels defining the severity of the accident: slight-serious-fatal. I want to build a classification model - multinomial logistic regression. A part of the independent variables have data related to the victim and this data is available only for serious and fatal accidents where there was actually a victim. Would it be correct to discard from the beginning these variables from the multinomial logistic regression model building?